# What's the difference between "lejos" and "alejados"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, adjetivos, adverbios, diferencias-entre-palabras

I've learned that both "lejos" and "alejados" mean "far" / "far away".

What are the differences between these words? When should you prefer one over the other?

Comment: That's an interesting question, Cal, and welcome to the site. // It's best practice to check at least one dictionary first, before asking, and include what you found there *in the body of your question.*

Comment: lejos and alejados are not parallel construction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"lejos" is an invariable adverb.

"alejado" is an adjective whose gender and number varies according to the noun to which it refers.

Both tend to appear within the predicate, after verbs like "estar", "encontrarse" or "quedar", but "lejos" is much more usual and "alejado/a/s" can sound a little more formal or literary. Also note that the verb "quedar" is only used for things.

Both "lejos" and "alejado/a/s" can also be used attributively (after, never before the noun they refer to) but will always tend to be followed by a prepositional phrase with "de":

- Vive en una **casa lejos de**l centro. (He/She lives in a house far from downtown.)
- Vive en una **casa alejada de**l centro. (He/She lives in a house far from downtown.)

There is an important difference between "lejos" and "alejado/a/s" and that is that "lejos" can refer to a temporary/occasional or permanent distance, while "alejado/a/s" almost always refers to a permanent distance and will thus tend to be used for properties or locations being far from other places.

- **(Nosotros)** Estamos / Nos encontramos **lejos** del centro (we are far from downtown). (**temporary or permanent distance**)
- **Nuestra casa** está / se encuentra / queda **lejos** del centro (our house is far from downtown). (**permanent distance**)
- **Nuestra casa** está / se encuentra / queda **alejada** del centro (our hourse if far from downtown). (**permanent distance**)

I recommend that you use "lejos" at all times: it's invariable and will always sound right.

Note: "estar alejado" (NOT "estar lejos") can be used for a temporary, emotional rather than physical distance, though in this case I prefer "estar distanciado", e.g. *Estoy alejado / distanciado de mi familia* (I am estranged from my family).

Comment: alejarse is also to distance oneself from someone: Quiero alejarme de ti. I want to get away from you or distance myself from you. And estar lejos de and estar alejado de **can be** translated in the same way in English sometimes.  You recommend always using lejos even when the meaning is the other one? estar alejado de mi familia is said in English: I'm not close to my family. It is not the very formal: to be estranged from.

Comment: @Lambie Have you read my final Note? There, I expressly recommend when not to use "estar lejos".

Comment: Yes, and the usual thing **one hears** is: alejarse and not distanciar. A family member of mine is in this situation. Never did that person say distanciadoi de. The person always says: alejada de mi familia. And yes, lejos is an adverb (my oversight saying it was an adjective) and is never "attributive": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attributive

Comment: @Lambie I hear "estar distanciado" a lot. It's a euphemistic way of saying "estar alejado", meaning you are not on speaking terms but not completely apart.

Comment: Google: "distanciado de su familia" at site:.es **10, 400** hits. "alejado de su familia" at site:.es: **197,000**. The numbers, at least for Spain, say otherwise. And, also, for site:.co, Colombia, for example. Many more alejados than distanciado. So...

Comment: @Lambie I didn't speak about one form prevailing over the other, but just of "estar distanciado" and "distanciarse" being heard a lot.

Comment: And where I said "attributive", I meant it can appear next to the noun in reduced relative clauses: "una casa lejos de la ciudad" = "una casa que está lejos de la ciudad". I never made the mistake of calling "lejos" an adjective.

Comment: But clearly they are not. And estranged is alienado. Una casa lejos del centro is adverbial: una casa que está lejos del centro. Yes, I made a mistake in calling it an adjective (even in English I was wrong) but my translations are all **accurate**.

Comment: They are used a lot. Check with CVC if you wish (but then say what the outcome is, not like you did with the "manzanas": https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101697/discussion-on-answer-by-user2325442-busco-problemas-donde-no-los-hay). *estranged from: no longer seeing or talking to a relative or good friend, because of an argument.* End of discussion.

Comment: estar alienado de la familia. To be estranged from one's family. And that other question about comprar. They guy at the Instituto Cervantes said my version with an object  was better, in fact. You can go look it up on their site. You decided to sit that one out. Remember? // You can "win" **Into Spanish** but not **into English**.  I know what estranged means: alienado. A formal word.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102995/discussion-between-gustavson-and-lambie).

Answer (score 0):

La casa queda lejos de la playa. The house **is far (away)** from the beach.

La casa [en le terreno] está alejada de la calle. The house is located away from the street. Or: The house is at a distance from the street. Or: The house is away from the street. Or: The house is not close to the street. Or: The house **is far away** from the street.

Be careful: **In English, in everyday language both **alejada** and **lejos** can be translated the same way in certain contexts.**

- Quiero alejarme de ti. I want to get away from you or **distance myself** from you.
- Quiere irme lejos de ti. I want to go far away from you.

**alejarse is a verb** and implies moving a distance away from a person or thing or being at a distance away from something or distancing oneself from something.

**lejos is just the adverb** for far away from.

**In English**, the only verb for **alejarse de alguien" is **to distance oneself from someone.** Otherwise, one has to use: *go far away from* or *get away from*.

Comment: Thanks for giving it some formatting!  I gave it a little more.  But you can easily do a rollback if you want to. // I'd suggest "**alejarse is a verb**" instead of "**alejar** is a verb" because the learner probably doesn't need both, and I think "alejarse" is the more important one for the learner.  You might also want to link to a post that explains about using the past participle as an adjective.

Comment: @aparente001 I used it as alejarse. No, I am not going to link it to anything. The basic points are there.

Comment: Thanks for adding the *se*.

Comment: "alejado" [is an adjective](https://dle.rae.es/alejado). "Lejos" [is an adverb](https://dle.rae.es/lejos).

Comment: @wimi alejado is an adjective formed from the **verb alejar**. Estar lejos de is not an adverb.

Comment: @wimi Yes, lejos de is an adverb. My bad. But everything else I said is accurate.

Comment: @Lambie you are right. I edited your post to remove the words "CORRECTION OF MY POST": such notices should be in comments. Everything else is accurate.

Comment: @wimi Yes, comments such as those should perhaps be in the comments. Though I am not sure that is a rule. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm contributing another answer because I sense that OP was hoping for a simple explanation without a lot of jargon.*

"Lejos" is an adverb and would be a common choice to describe the location of something, for example

- Su casa está lejos de aquí. | *Her house is far away [from here].*

"Alejado" is an adjective, and is often used for emotional distance, for example

- Desde que se murió mi tía, mis primos han estado un poco alejados de nosotros. | *Since my aunt died, my cousins have been been a bit distant.*

It is also possible, but less common, to use "alejado" to mean "far" or "far away" in the sense of "remote," for example:

- El aeropuerto está alejado del centro. | *The airport is far from the center of town* [meaning that it was built at a distance from town].

As an adjective, "alejado" will need to agree with the noun it describes, in number and gender.  Here's an example with a feminine noun:

- La estación no está tan alejada del centro. | *The station is not as far from town.*

(For a more complete listing of sample sentences and possible usages, I would encourage you to check some dictionaries.)